# Estimate how many wrong measures there is in a sample

Tags: sample, central-limit-theorem, measurement-error

[This study](https://www.bmj.com/content/350/bmj.h1193) shows that the average penis mean is 13.24cm and the standard deviation is 1.89cm. Let's suppose we have a population with this mean and standard deviation for penis length.

Suppose we ask 30 men in this population what their penis lengths are. Suppose that the selection of 30 men is so that all men from the population have the same probability of being selected. Can we know how many of them are lying about their penis length?

Of course, if we calculate a sample mean of 18 cm, we can, based on the central limit theorem say that this sample is an outlier or that there is people lying about their penis size. But can we create a model to estimate how many of them are lying?

Comment: "Too low so this sample probably has people lying about the penis length." -- only if the sample was obtained from the same population as the study.  Male genitalia likely varies country to country (likely due to genetic factors associated with demography).

Comment: But assuming that the comparison is permissible, I don't think is is possible.  The sample mean is a function of the entire sample, and so it could be that there was simply one (very poor) liar which has dragged up the sample mean whereas the others were truthful, or even perhaps modest which would result in a bias in the other direction.

Estimating the number of subjects who exaggerated their measurement would require strong assumptions difficult to justify with only the information presented here.

Comment: I suppose an "error in variables" approach might be taken, but again this relies on assumptions not justifiable through the information presented alone.

Comment: Calling outliers “wrong” or “liars” is incorrect. Bill Gates or Elon Musk are not lying about their fortune because they diverge from the average.

Comment: ok but suppose I challenge you:
You and I say a number, then I take an unbiased sample of 100_000_000 people from the world. I will take the sum of the squared error of both mine and your guess in relation to the fortune of those people, and both of us need to pay the error in dollars to the other. If you did not said the mean of fortunes, probably you will lose money even though can be there an Elon musk that will rise the mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figure out the solution. Please, someone, confirm if I am right.

First, we need to know the distribution of penis length from the population we take this sample from. It's common to assume that measures of body parts are normally distributed, so we can use the normal dist.

We will not use the sample mean, but the individual measures of the sample. Let us start with a sample of 3 people with these values (16,17,19) to demonstrate how would be the algorithm for 30 values.

Lets see all possible cases.

For 0 liars we have:

S S S (see the explanation in the next value)

For 1 liar we have:

L S S  (this means first is Liar, second and third are sincere).

S L S

S S L

**For 2:**

L L S

L S L

S L L

**for 3:**

L L L

Lets take the first elements that said 16. The probably of he is sincere is:

$P(15 < X < 17)$  - Thoses are all values that has less than 1cm of error with 16.

the probability of he is lying is $1 - P(15 < X < 17) $ then.

Lets calculate all probabilities for our table:

**For 0:**

S S S = $(P(15 < X < 17))*(P(16 < X < 18))*(P(18 < X < 20))$

**For 1:**

L S S = $(1 - P(15 < X < 17))*(P(16 < X < 18))*(P(18 < X < 20))$

S L S = $(P(15 < X < 17))*(1 - P(16 < X < 18))*(P(18 < X < 20))$

S S L = $(P(15 < X < 17))*(P(16 < X < 18))*(1 - P(18 < X < 20))$

**For 2:**
L L S = $(1 - P(15 < X < 17))*(1 - P(16 < X < 18))*(1 - P(18 < X < 20))$

L S L = $(1 - P(15 < X < 17))*(P(16 < X < 18))*(1 - P(18 < X < 20))$

S L L = $(P(15 < X < 17))*(1 - P(16 < X < 18))*(1 - P(18 < X < 20))$

**for 3:**
L L L = $(1 - P(15 < X < 17))*(1 - P(16 < X < 18))*(1 - P(18 < X < 20))$

lets calculate all values for the table using (using the normal distribution CDF, remember we are supposing the real mean is 13.24 and std is 1.89):

**For 0:**

S S S = $(0.1525)*(0.0662)*(0.0057) = 0.000057544349999999994$

**For 1:**

L S S = $(1 - 0.1525)*(0.0662)*(0.0057) = 0.00031979565$

S L S = $(0.1525)*(1 - 0.0662)*(0.0057) = 0.0008117056499999999$

S S L = $(0.1525)*(0.0662)*(1 - 0.0057) = 0.010037955649999998$

**For 2:**
L L S = $(1 - 0.1525)*(1 - 0.0662)*(0.0057) = 0.0045109543500000005$

L S L = $(1 - 0.1525)*(0.0662)*(1 - 0.0057) = 0.05578470434999999$

S L L = $(0.1525)*(1 - 0.0662)*(1 - 0.0057) = 0.14159279435$

**for 3:**
L L L = $(1 - 0.1525)*(1 - 0.0662)*(1 - 0.0057) = 0.78688454565$

Lets sum up all the probabilities, Lets use N as a random variable to represent the number of liars:

$P(N = 0) = 0.000057544349999999994$

$P(N = 1) = 0.00031979565 + 0.0008117056499999999 + 0.010037955649999998 = 0.011169456949999998$

$P(N = 2) = 0.0045109543500000005 + 0.05578470434999999 + 0.14159279435 = 0.20188845304999997$

$P(N = 3) = 0.78688454565$

Lets calculate the expected value of N:

$E(N) = 0.000057544349999999994*0 + 0.011169456949999998*1 + 0.20188845304999997*2 + 0.78688454565*3$

$E(N) = 2.7756$

So, on average, samples with the measures [16,17,19] will have 2.78 liars, witch means that probably all of them are lying.

Now we do this algorithm to the sample of size 30.

Comment: An approach like this cannot possibly be correct, because all you need is one whopping big lie to raise the average to any conceivable value.  The conclusion that everybody in a sample with an unusual mean is lying is not only mathematically wrong, it is ethically wrong, too, because you are imputing to an entire group the characteristics of an unknown, unidentified, and possibly tiny subgroup.  -1.

Comment: explain please. Having everybody lying in a sample is possible and we can associate a probability to it, right?

Comment: It is possible, but you cannot determine a probability.  With the information given in your question that probability could be anywhere between 0 and 1 inclusive.  For instance, you haven't described how the sample was obtained.  It could be a sample of very special people and everyone could be giving correct values.  Or it could be a sample of ordinary people but they're telling the truth because they are using an erroneous measurement device.  Even if it's a random sample of a population with known characteristics, you have no basis to conclude there is more than one false result.

Comment: Ok, I will change some info of my question so that it can represent the idea of a sample without bias. But the idea is: given all possible samples with those values, how many of them have liars? Of course there are outliers, but I'm talking about the average here.

Comment: Again, that's unanswerable for the reasons I gave.  *A single outlying value can change the average by an arbitrary amount.*

Comment: Of course, outliers can exist, but, for instance, in fraud detection, we normally try to detect outliers and assume that outliers are cases worth investigating. I tried to calculate how many liars, on average, would exist in all possible samples with the same values as the sample we take. And I'm assuming this is the number of liars. Is my calculation really calculating this or is there an error?

Comment: There's an error because that calculation cannot be done without adducing information not present in the question.

Comment: What information? If I'm correct (and there is a high chance I'm not) the only assumption I add is assuming penis length is normally distributed.